# Error Importing Jar to Android Project

Tags: android, dex

This is a recently problem with the new SDK for Android.

Now Android SDK uses the ANT convention when import external jars to the apk package, the external jars must be on the "lib" folder and the SDK ever will export the jars from that folder.

My problem is when i add my jars and run my project i get this message:

> trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.

i have read about this message here and other forums, some people says that the Android.jar is the problem so removing  will fix it.

But i can't found that Android.jar, except the Android librar that can't be removed.

This issue about import libraries to android it's making me mad because my application was working very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a bunch of issues when I first updated as well, but was eventually able to get it working.  Some suggestions, based on what eventually worked for me as well as a friend:

Make sure you have your external jars in a "libs" folder in the project's base directory (note the "s" here--not "lib"). If you make any changes, be sure to refresh the project and clean (then rebuild if not set to build automatically).

In your project properties under Java Build Path > Libraries tab, remove everything but the Android X.X.X and Android Dependencies nodes.  Again if you make any changes, be sure to refresh the project and clean (then rebuild if not set to build automatically).

If you've done this for your project and all library projects it uses in your workspace and are still having trouble, try removing all Android library projects (from project properties > Android) as well as all libraries from the Java Build Path (including Android X.X.X and Android dependencies this time) from each, clean, and then changing the Android version/applying/changing it back to force a rebuild.  (Do this for each project starting with your base library project, only adding them to your other projects once they build without errors).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks :) i solved (at last !!) removing a couple of jars that are included on Android SDK

Comment: This works. Another (more radical) way to go about it is to back-up libs and delete everything in it then re-introduce the files one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Once try to clean your project and built it again...it might help you...because it help me...i was also having the same problem with my new sdk...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on a test project, when I was building with Maven. I solved it by adding

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

to the android test libraries.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```